# How do I group and display my JSON data on the page based on the multi-filter selection?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I currently have 3 select box multi-filters which pulls data from a JSON file. I need the page to display all of the relevant JSON data based on the selection of the filters. For example after selecting country, state & city, the page will display the selected JSON data as well as the other values in the relevant JSON group.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="width:600px;">
    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="">Select country</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="">Select state</option>
    </select>
    <br />
    <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
        <option value="">Select city</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

load_json_data('country');

function load_json_data(id, parent_id) {
    var html_code = '';
    $.getJSON('./data/country_state_city.json', function(data) {

        html_code += '<option value="">Select ' + id + '</option>';
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            if (id == 'country') {
                if (value.parent_id == '0') {
                    html_code += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>';
                }
            } else {
                if (value.parent_id == parent_id) {
                    html_code += '<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.name + '</option>';
                }
            }
        });
        $('#' + id).html(html_code);
    });

}

$(document).on('change', '#country', function() {
    var country_id = $(this).val();
    if (country_id != '') {
        load_json_data('state', country_id);
    } else {
        $('#state').html('<option value="">Select state</option>');
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
    }
});
$(document).on('change', '#state', function() {
    var state_id = $(this).val();
    if (state_id != '') {
        load_json_data('city', state_id);
    } else {
        $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
    }
});

});
```

**JSON**

```
[
 {
  "id":"1",
  "name":"USA",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"2",
  "name":"Canada",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"3",
  "name":"Australia",
  "parent_id":"0"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"4",
  "name":"New York",
  "parent_id":"1"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"5",
  "name":"Alabama",
  "parent_id":"1"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"6",
  "name":"California",
  "parent_id":"1"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"7",
  "name":"Ontario",
  "parent_id":"2"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"8",
  "name":"British Columbia",
  "parent_id":"2"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"9",
  "name":"New South Wales",
  "parent_id":"3"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"10",
  "name":"Queensland",
  "parent_id":"3"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"11",
  "name":"New York city",
  "parent_id":"4"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"12",
  "name":"Buffalo",
  "parent_id":"4"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"13",
  "name":"Albany",
  "parent_id":"4"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"14",
  "name":"Birmingham",
  "parent_id":"5"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"15",
  "name":"Montgomery",
  "parent_id":"5"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"16",
  "name":"Huntsville",
  "parent_id":"5"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"17",
  "name":"Los Angeles",
  "parent_id":"6"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"18",
  "name":"San Francisco",
  "parent_id":"6"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"19",
  "name":"San Diego",
  "parent_id":"6"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"20",
  "name":"Toronto",
  "parent_id":"7"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"21",
  "name":"Ottawa",
  "parent_id":"7"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"22",
  "name":"Vancouver",
  "parent_id":"8"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"23",
  "name":"Victoria",
  "parent_id":"8"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"24",
  "name":"Sydney",
  "parent_id":"9"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"25",
  "name":"Newcastle",
  "parent_id":"9"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"26",
  "name":"City of Brisbane",
  "parent_id":"10"
 }, 
 {
  "id":"27",
  "name":"Gold Coast",
  "parent_id":"10"
 }
]
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking here. Are you getting errors with the displayed markup/logic? Is there a formatting question about how to display information? Please update your question to make it clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are making multiple changes in a short period of time. JavaScript is a powerful tool, but you can save time by using a library to enhance your capabilities and streamline your future projects. I recommend considering React or Angular. For React, you can explore Vite. [Vite React Link](https://vitejs.dev/guide/)

On the other hand, you should consider changing some properties of your objects. For example

```
{
 "id":"1",
 "name":"USA",
 "city" : "X City"
 "state" : "X State"
 "time-zone" "X time-z"
 },

// opt 2 

{
"id" : 1,
 "country" : "USA:,
    "cities" : {
              ... cities, 
                   {
                   "id":"1",
                   "name":"X name",
                   "time-zone" "X time-z"
                   },
                }
    }
```

Onces you add those values you filter in many orders as you want, first filter by state, then filter by city and last filter by time-zone, then you get all the objects that matches all the requirements. [How to use filter on JS](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/filter-arrays-in-javascript/)